# ZSH autocompletion deny previous command?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

E.g. I write the command `cat file.txt` and my cursor currently in the end of the string if I try to press arrow down or up I won't allow me to traverse over history, I should only press `Ctrl+C` to decline this command. Is any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: The default behaviour is to search history for commands beginning with (in this case) `cat file.txt`, what you want is just to go through your command history in order?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander exactly

Comment: I think you want `bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-history` https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control